# Java While Loop for ArrayList can't get data in Array

Tags: java

I'm trying to use menu loop than when I finish the first choice an I want to get data in choice 2.
It can't get, this is an error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:425)
        at craitid_19.main(craitid-19.java:38)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
class craitid_19{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        while(true){
        System.out.println("1 - Insert");
        System.out.println("2 - Edit");
        System.out.println("3 - View");
        System.out.println("4 - Exit");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        infected patient = new infected();

        switch (choice){
        case 1: 
            System.out.print("ID = ");
            int id = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("name = ");
            String name = input.next();
            System.out.print("age = ");
            String age = input.next();
            System.out.print("gender = ");
            String gender = input.next();
            System.out.print("date = ");
            String date = input.next();
            System.out.print("province = ");
            String province = input.next();
            System.out.print("infectby = ");
            String infectby = input.next();
            patient.children.add(new normal(id, name, age, gender, date, province, infectby));
            System.out.print(patient.toString());
            continue;


        case 2:
            System.out.println("Insert ID");
            System.out.print(patient.children.get(0));

        case 4:
            System.out.println("Exiting Program...");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default :
             System.out.println("This is not a valid Menu Option! Please Select Another");
             break;
        }
        }
    }
}
class infected {    
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String age;
    public String gender;
    public String date;
    public String province;
    public String infectby;
    public String type;

    public List<infected> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public infected(){
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
    String returnString = id + (",") + name + (",") + age + (",") + gender + (",") + date + (",") + province + (",") + infectby + (",") + type + System.lineSeparator();
    for (infected child : children) 
    returnString = child.toString() + System.lineSeparator();
    return returnString;
    }
}

class normal extends infected{
    public normal(int id, String name, String age, String gender, String date, String province, String infectby){
        type = "1";
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.date = date;
        this.province = province;
        this.infectby = infectby;

    }


}
```

Comment: Have you used `continue` instead of `break` accidentally? Also, you do not have `break` in `case 2`.

Comment: Declare `infected patient = new infected();` outside of the main method. It's a local variable which is getting instantiated on every loop.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that.
In case 2 I want to check data in ArrayList but until I put break in case 2 it has the same error.

Comment: Thanks akash, haha I solve that error.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you create **infected patient** inside of while loop. This means you override the data you created every time when you answer the menu. The error actually says that you patient.children List is empty, while you are trying to get the 0 element. So I recommend:

1. Move initialization of patient object out of while loop (just put it before while).
2. Check if the list is not empty before you try to read data from it.
3. Use Java naming convention for classes (they should start from uppercase letter - Infected instead of infected an so on) - this will make your code much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to replace `continue;` by `break;` Then, between line 4 and 5 you have to add this:

```
infected patient = new infected();
```

This will call just once the class and the class' constructor, if you want to call the constructor of the class each time the loop repeats you just add

```
infected patient,
```

And in the line 13 you replace what you have for:

```
patient = new infected();
```

**What's the difference between calling the constructor just once or each time the loop repeats?**

- In the first case, when you add a patient it will remain until you close the program,
- In the second case, each time the loop repeats, the patient you added before will be lost.

Choose wisely.
You also should use the Java name convention, the first letter of the classes' name must be uppercase.